# Github Actions: Build NextJS Project in Different Directory

Tags: next.js, github-actions, pm2

I'm wondering how I would go about building my project in a sibling directory to the existing repo. The reason for this is that I will occasionally get errors when builds fail and leave something messed up in the build directory. It seems like it would be far more ideal to build in a separate directory, then if the build succeeds, move all files to the actual running directory and restart PM2. I know I can use working-directory in the .yml, but I'm not sure how exactly to write this to ensure that there won't be any downtime. If this isn't a good solution and anyone has any other ideas, I am open to them. Here's my current deploy file:

````
name: Staging Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: Staging
    environment: Staging

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm install
    - name: Create env file
      run: |
        touch .env
        ...create env file with repo secrets
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - name: Restart PM2
      id: restart_pm2
      run: pm2 reload reponame
      continue-on-error: true
    - name: Start PM2
      if: steps.restart_pm2.outcome != 'success'
      run: pm2 start pm2.config.js```
````

Comment: I guess that ‘runs-on: Staging’ is a self hosted runner then? Best practice is to clean up whatever you do on them (or even better, make the runner ephemeral to avoid these issues completely!). 

So then I would recommend copying the files to another directly and run the build from there. If that is successful, stop PM2 (whatever that is), copy the build output to it, and the start PM2 again. 

Even better would be to separate your CI (that should deliver the artifact) and CD. Then you can eliminate these kinds of issues as well, by running on different runners.

Comment: @RobBos just to clarify... a system of ephemeral runners would involve spinning up a new server with each build, and once the build succeeds, destroy the old server with the previous build. Is that how it works?

Comment: Correct. I run my own set of self-hosted runners in a Kubernetes cluster, making this a lot easier (if you know k8s already). There is a whole slew of options for doing so, which can be found in this repo: https://github.com/jonico/awesome-runners

Answer (score -2):

Modify the pm2 reload step to reload the app from the running directory. You can do this by specifying the path to the running directory as the working directory for the reload step. For example:

```
    name: Restart PM2
    id: restart_pm2
    run: pm2 reload reponame
    working-directory: .
    continue-on-error: true
```

By following these steps, you should be able to build your project in a separate directory and move the built files to the running directory without any downtime. It's a good idea to test this process on a staging environment before deploying to production to ensure that everything is working as expected.

Comment: Moving the new build files to the working dir would cause issues though. I would have to reload pm2 from the new build dir.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).